# Surpass "Touch to Beam" while using NFC Reader - Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, nfc

I'm developing an application using Ionic framework. The app uses Phonegap-NFC. When a textrecord is sent, the app asks for the user to tap on the screen to "beam" the message to the reciever.

I would like to make my app as automatic as possible, so my question is: how can i disable-or make the android's "touch to beam" message hidden/go away?

Also I have looked into the other questions concerning this problematic situation - I am curious if it has been surpassed since those. A donation is up for a solution.
Thank you!